# Do we really need to distinguish between the tags "countable-nouns" and "uncountable-nouns"?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

It seems to me that most of the questions about the one topic will also be related to the other. So why not have a single overarching tag like [count-noncount](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/count-noncount) or [countability](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/countability), and make [countable-nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/countable-nouns) and [uncountable-nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncountable-nouns) synonyms of this?

I think a parallel case is the use of a single tag for [grammatical-number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-number) rather than separate tags for [singular](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singular) and [plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plural).

Since I'm talking about this, I'll also mention that the tag [count](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/count) seems of questionable usefulness to me; one of the questions tagged with it is about the countable-uncountable distinction, while others seem to be either about grammatical number or counting.

Anyway, do you agree with me? If so, what do you think is the best name for a tag about countable and uncountable uses of nouns? I'm leaning towards [count-noncount](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/count-noncount), which you can find a lot of Google hits for, with [countable-nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/countable-nouns), [uncountable-nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uncountable-nouns) and their synonyms being made synonyms of this single tag.

Comment: Recently at Meta.ELL: *[Let's merge 'passive-voice' and 'active-voice'](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2478)*.

Comment: You make a good point. I’d like to see more community discussion though.